# How to set preferences variables in oracle JET

Tags: oracle-jet, mcs

[image]While integrating Oracle MAF with Oracle MCS, Authorization variables like Mobilebackend Id,Anonymous Id are given by end user.They were actually given as preference variables.

This is the MAF Application where end user can manually set the Mobile Cloud Service Settings.Likewise ,how can I do the same in oracle JET ?

Whether I have to create global variables and assign them in below part?

```
var mcs_config = {

    "logLevel": mcs.LOG_LEVEL.INFO,

    "logHTTP": true,

    "mobileBackends": {

        "MyJETApp": {

            "default": true,

            "baseUrl": "https://xx.mobileenv.us2.oraclecloud.com:443",

            "applicationKey": applicationkey,

            "authorization": {

                "basicAuth": {

                    "backendId": "e53739ff-bea5-4250-8cf4-967798cbd497",

                    "anonymousToken": "UE1FTkFCTEVGRUIxN19QTUVOQUJMRUZFQl9NT0JJTEVfQU5PTllNT1VTX0FQUElEOkxpdjB3YXpwcy55ZDZn"

                }

            }

        }

    }

};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is publishing videos on JET+MCS here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2ux0DjE-RYe-B3jPw1P6kuqsz7OMu6W1

The first video shows you how to configure the MCS client SDKs with JET, which will address your question.

The following article also describes the process: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-mash-up-jet-and-mcs-mobile-apps

Comment: Thanks Chris.I have already  gone through the video .I have edited my question .Can you please clarify it to me?

Comment: Janaki, can you take these questions over to the OTN forums for MCS please, the Stackoverflow interface doesn't suit this style of questions where we need to have a back-forward discussion with you on what you're attempting to really achieve: https://community.oracle.com/community/oracle-mobile/oracle-mobile-cloud-service/content

Comment: can you please help me to solve this issue??

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520553/swipe-to-reveal-is-not-working